# can access jagged array by foreach loop in c#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, jagged-arrays

how to access **jagged** array by **foreach** in C#.net?

> How can  do this?

Comment: Look at the https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4):

```
int[][] jaggedArray = new int[][] 
{
    new int[] { 0, 1, 2 },
    new int[] { 3, 4 },
    new int[] { 5 }
};
foreach (int[] array in jaggedArray)
{
    foreach (int value in array)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use linq

```
foreach (int item in jaggedarray.SelectMany(i => i))
{
    // work with item
}
```